# ubuntu.stackexchange.com is down

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, subdomains

It looks like the problems haven't quite ended yet.

[image]

As far as I knew, the *.SE redirects were permanent and would always point to the actual domain.

Comment: working for me...

Comment: working for me too—have you flushed your DNS cache? I seem to remember Jeff mentioning that was causing the same thing to happen for chats.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it is a cache issue after all.

Comment: If this was a cache issue, I am going to close this as too localized. If that wasn't the case, please flag to re-open.

Comment: I'm seeing this too

Comment: @Robert: It seems like there is more to this issue than first suspected... see Kyle's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ubuntu.stackexchange.com alias was lost during a recent edit of our sites table.  This should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this too. I get a 404 when I try to telnet into the IP I get from dig. Requesting `apple.stackexchange.com` from the same IP works fine:

```
London-2:~ kyle$ dig ubuntu.stackexchange.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> ubuntu.stackexchange.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7817
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ubuntu.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ubuntu.stackexchange.com. 1403 IN A 64.34.119.12

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 28 22:47:33 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58

London-2:~ kyle$ telnet 64.34.119.12 80
Trying 64.34.119.12...
Connected to stackoverflow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ubuntu.stackexchange.com

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 29 Dec 2010 03:47:51 GMT
Content-Length: 3449




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Site not found: ubuntu.stackexchange.com</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stackexchange.com/Content/all.css?v=56a356499730" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://stackexchange.com/favicon.ico">
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="contentWrapper">
                        <input id="search" type="text" name="q" size="31" title=                </div>form>
                        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/about/management">        </section>nav>ul>
                    <li><a href="http://stackexchange.com/" >Hot Questions</a></                    <li><a href="http://stackexchange.com/tagsets" >Tagged Quest                    <li><a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites" >All Sites</a><                    <li><a href="http://stackexchange.com/leagues" >Top Users</a        </header>>ul>
            <img src="http://stackexchange.com/content/img/panda-huh.jpg" style="float: right; margin: 15px 0 15px 30px" />
                    The Q&amp;A site <b>ubuntu.stackexchange.com</b> doesn't see                    You can vote for it to be created through our democratic, community-driven process at <a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com">area51.stack                    or see a complete directory of all our Q&amp;A sites at <a h                    If you are the administrator of a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, please contact <a href="mailto:rcartaino@stackoverflow.com">Robert Cartaino</a> w        </section>p>u may have.
    </div>
            <p><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/about/management">about</a> <a href="http://blog.stackexchange.com">blog</a> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/legal">legal</a> <a href="mailto:team@stackexchange.com">contact us</a> <a href=            <p>site design / logo &copy; 2010 stack overflow internet services,     </footer>>ributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required</p>

</body>
</html>Connection closed by foreign host.
London-2:~ kyle$
```

Comment: Odd. I just tried the exact same thing, and got a 301 Moved Permanently.

Comment: @waiwai933 did you send the request to the same IP as I have in my post?

Comment: Yep. [Here's the output.](https://gist.github.com/758157)

Comment: I tried that IP and got the SO homepage.

Comment: @Jon: That's because you omitted the `host` HTTP header.

Comment: @George: Oops, yeah. I get a 301 now.